# How to create ajax crawable in asp.net

Tags: ajax, web-crawler, pretty-urls

**How to create token "#!" in asp.net mvc?**

**How to create html snapshot?**

I have read google document, They talk create "Indicate to the crawler that your site supports the AJAX crawling scheme" by www.example.com/ajax.html#key=value to change www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value.

But in asp.net mvc 4 I can't how to create "#!" because when i use @Ajax.ActionLink("link text", "controller", new { attribute router here },new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod="GET", InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId ="id to add function of ajax"}). So it gernater "action/?key=valuer" not like i expected "action/#!key=value"

So somebody help me. I want to google crawble link when ajax function do when i click a text and ajax function excute

what is html snapshot, is this create after when i excute ajax function( click text and ajax function do gernater hmtl to UpdattagetId(I code in asp mvc). So i can dont change any thing with existing i haved code: Ajax.actionlink(...) and gernerater html to UpdatetargetId)